# Running Clover coverage reporter inserts new column to CSV test and breaks build

Tags: java, testing, maven-3, clover

I am trying to integrate Clover with a Java project at work. Clover has been added to the classpath, the plugin has been added to the POM and the license has been set up. 
When I run `mvn clean clover:setup test clover:aggregate clover:clover` Clover starts up correctly. However, tests that generate csv's fail because the CSV output is not what is expected. This is what gets generated for one of the tests:

```
<ID,NAME,[__CLR4_1_2_TEST_NAME_SNIFFER,"DESCRIPTION,Long","DESCRIPTION,Short",country
001,Fred,com_atlassian_clover.TestNameSniffer$1@e628ccb,Mr. Fred Flinstone,Fred Flinstone,US
002,Bob,com_atlassian_clover.TestNameSniffer$1@e628ccb,Mr. Bob the builder,Bob the builder,UK
003,Tintin,com_atlassian_clover.TestNameSniffer$1@e628ccb,Mr. Tin Tin,Tin Tin,FR
004,,com_atlassian_clover.TestNameSniffer$1@e628ccb,,Rob the Bob,
005,,com_atlassian_clover.TestNameSniffer$1@e628ccb],,Tom the Bob,
>
```

This is what is expected:

```
<ID,NAME,["DESCRIPTION,Long","DESCRIPTION,Short",country
001,Fred,Mr. Fred Flinstone,Fred Flinstone,US
002,Bob,Mr. Bob the builder,Bob the builder,UK
003,Tintin,Mr. Tin Tin,Tin Tin,FR
004,,,Rob the Bob,
005,],,Tom the Bob,
```

Why would Clover add a new column in to the CSV output, is it possible to stop it? I'm using maven 3.3, JDK 8 and Clover version 4.0.2.

I have tried looking for an answer but cannot seem to find anything similar to this issue. When I remove the failing tests Clover works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's connected to the code (or a library) you're using to create that CSV file. Clover on its own won't modify a CSV file. I suppose there's a code which access Java Object fields by reflection. Since class is instrumented by Clover, it adds some instrumentation code (like *CLV_TEST_SNIFFER*.

There are basically two solutions to your problem:

- Modify the code which dumps classes to CSV to exclude static class members (this will effectively exclude Clover objects). Anyway, I believe it's not desired to dump static members to CSV which, as I assume, is a data projection of your Java object (static members don't belong to object but to class). Though, I don't know your full use case, so I may be simply wrong.
- You can simply [exclude files](https://docs.atlassian.com/clover-maven-plugin/latest/setup-mojo.html#excludesFile) which cause problems (the ones which are serialised to CSV?) from Clover instrumentation, effectively you'll loose coverage data for those classes.

Comment: Went with just excluding those files. Thanks!